# what is error in my code of java. not compiling

Tags: java

What is the error in my code? The code is not compiling, only giving compiling error at `add.persons(p);`

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class AddressBook
{
    ArrayList personInfo;

    public AddressBook()
    {
        persons=new ArrayList();
    }
    public void addperson()
    {
        String name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name of the person ");
        String address=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter address of the person ");
        String phoneNum =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter phone number of the person ");
    }
        personInfo p = new personInfo(name, address, phoneNum);
        persons.add(p);
        public void searchPerson(String n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<persons.size(); i++)
            {
                PersonInfo p= (personInfo)person(i);
                if (n.equals(p.name))
                {
                    p.printPersonInfo();
                }

            }
        }
        public void deletPerson(String n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<persons.size(); i++)
            {
                PersonInfo p= (personInfo)person(i);
                if (n.equals(p.name))
                {
                    person.remove(i);
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You can only have statements inside a method, constructor or code block. You can't have code floating like that. I highly recommend you use the code formatter in your IDE. It will help you recognise this sort of issue quickly. I also suggest you use a generic `List<PersonInfo> persons` as this will simplify your code and avoid certain bugs.

Comment: You should add more information about the compiler error. What the error says, in what line it occurs etc... For this question it's not necessary anymore, but for the future it is always good to add all relevant information. :)

Answer (score 2):

move this

```
personInfo p = new personInfo(name, address, phoneNum);
persons.add(p);
```

inside a method and everything will work....